# Expressing a constant in function of other prefixed constants - TI-Nspire CAS

Tags: ti-nspire

I'm trying to do the following operation with my TI-Nspire CAS; I have:

x=a+b

y=a-c

I'd like to get:

y=x-b-c

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Se := instead of =.

Comment: Hello @soegaard, I tryed x:=a+b and y=a-c, and x:=a+b and y:=a-c, but both solutions don't work; the result is always y=a-c instead of y=x-b-c. Thank you for your help and happy Easter.

Comment: How about. Solve( x=a+b and y=a-c , {y,x,b})

Comment: I get the result: x=a+c1 and y=a-c and b=c1. Maybe TI-Nspire CAS can't do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
i1:=solve(x=a+b,a)
y:=a-c|i1
```

Comment: if you want, I have another question for your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600201/constant-in-function-of-other-constants-ti-nspire-cas